# Backbone.js routing with url as query string

Tags: backbone.js, routes

I have Backbone js application and i have setup the router and now i try to pass url parameter as query string.

```
routes: {
   'login?r=:query': 'doSomthing'
}
```

Can someone help me to pass url(http://someurl.org/dsfgsdjfsdgf) us query parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question i found the right answer

```
router: {
 'login?r:*query': 'dosomthing'
}
```